# Bootstrap Toggle Checkbox is not working in Partial View

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

In index view, I have modal div

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">

    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div id='myModalContent2' class="modal-content">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Loading this modal div with partial view, which contains checkbox toggle button.

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row">
       <div>
             <input type="checkbox" id="chkStatus" class="IsActive" name="Status" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Active" data-off="Inactive">
        </div>
      </div>                            
</div>
```

Initially, toggle button not shown. For this I have added bootstrap-toggle css and bootstrap-toggle js in partial view. Now toggle checkbox is working on alternate page loads. First time it is working. If we close the popup and try again it is not working. close and try again working. What is the cause?

popup is launching on a button click.